# Why does my content.js not run when i use a navbar?

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon-webextensions

My content script does not run when i go from one page to another using a navbar. I made a simple console.log() to check if my content script ran when i used the navbar, it does not log anything.
Content script:

```
Console.log("Hello")
```

My manifest v2 looks like the following:

```
{

  "manifest_version": 2,
  "name": "Placeholder",
  "version": "1.1.5",

  "background": {
    "scripts":["background.js"]
  },

  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": ["https://placeholder/follows*"],
      "js": ["content.js"]
    }
]
}
```

The content script does not run when I go from placeholder/updates to placeholder/follows. When going from updates to follows i expect to see **Hello** in the console.
The navbutton looks like the following:

```
<a href="/follows"></a>
```

Comment: The site is a SPA, so the page stays the same whereas content scripts run only when it's created. You can use MutationObserver to detect changes in the page or use browser.tabs.onUpdated with a url filter in your background script and send a message to the content script when it fires.

Comment: You probably want to add event listener to browser history